# How to get pointer events working in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, wkwebview, pointer-events

I am looking for a way to run the event pointers under WKWebview.

More precisely, to be able to differentiate the finger of the apple pencil under iPad pro for example, to be able to write in a canvas.

Otherwise, do you know libs or a way to make the apple work pencil in a WKWebview?

Maybe detect the pencil natively and notifie javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved with : https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/31124

Using the force property of touch event, we can differentiate the pen from the finger.